# Can someone help me change this to just one line of code?

Tags: python

Can someone help me simplify these lines of code to just one please

```
x = 1.0
a = float(input('Ingrese el valor de a: \n'))
for k in range(1, 10):
    x = (x + a/x)/2
print(x)
```

Comment: what's the point of that?

Comment: @BuddyBob implement it in a lambda function and learn it that I don't quite understand how, I don't know if you can help me

Comment: The code is wrong. For loop does not return anything, so you cannot set some value to it.

Comment: @BarishNamazov Inadvertently copying a wrong function is fine, can you help me please and I just started recently and it's my first day here

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you are looking for, but this code uses Newton's Method to calculate the square root with 10 iterations. You can use one-liner if you would like to calculate sqrt:

```
print(float(input("Enter a number: "))**0.5)
```

---

I don't think it would be possible to do the exact same code as you have in one line since you would probably need to import `reduce` from `functools`, but that makes it at least two lines. ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code though I don't think this kind of code will be of any use outside something like code golf.

```py
(lambda x, a: print((lambda f: f(x, a, 1, f))(lambda x, a, i, rec: x if i >= 10 else rec((x+a/x)/2, a, i+1, rec))))(1.0, float(input('Ingrese el valor de a: \n')))
```